# Yii2: How do I write the below Active Query?

Tags: yii2, yii2-model

Using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22972500/3128638), how can I get my `$conditions` variable to my active query?

```
$conditions = 'main_category_id != :main_category_id', ['category_status' => 1, 'main_category_id' => 0, 'sub_category_id' => $id,'type'=> 4];

$result = Category::find()->where($conditions)->orderby('category_name ASC')->all();
```

On my query `main_category_id != 0`. Any other solution that works is also fine

Please note that I need `$conditions` variable as they vary. Here is my query with if statements:

```
    public function get_subcategory_list($id="",$type="")
{
    $conditions = ['category_status' => 1, 'main_category_id' => 0, 'main_category_id' => $id, 'type' => 2];
    if($type == 2){
        $conditions = ['category_status' => 1, 'main_category_id' => 0, 'sub_category_id' => $id, 'type' => 3];
    }
    if($type == 3){
        $conditions = ['category_status' => 1, 'main_category_id' => 0, 'sub_category_id' => $id,'type'=> 4];
    }
    $result = Category::find()->where($conditions)->orderby('category_name ASC')->all();
    return $result;
}
```

Please note that `$conditions` works fine on the above function the only problem is here `main_category_id` should not be equal to 0.

Comment: In the first condition assignment - `'main_category_id' => 0, 'main_category_id' => $id`. Is it a typo? Shoudn't it be `'main_category_id' => 0, 'sub_category_id' => $id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign variable (`$conditions`) like you did, it's not valid.

Your `ActiveQuery` can be written like this:

```
$models = Category::find()
    ->where(['<>', 'main_category_id', 0])
    ->andWhere([
        'category_status' => 1,
        'sub_category_id' => $subCategoryId,
        'type'=> 4,
    ])
    ->orderBy(['category_name' => SORT_DESC])
    ->all();
```

You can replace `<>` with `!=` or `not in` in case of using array of main category ids.

Read more about constructing `where` conditions in [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where%28%29-detail).

**Update:** No need to change the whole `$conditions` array and copy-paste. You can calculate the `$type` for example like this:

```
switch ($type) {
    case 2:
        $typeValue = 3;

        break;
    case 3:
        $typeValue = 4;

        break;
    default:
        $typeValue = 2;
}
```

This logic is a little bit weird (maybe increment +1 will be better).

Then just insert `$typeValue` instead of static value here `'type'=> $typeValue`.

Even you have some complex query constructing, you can divide query in separate `where` / `orWhere` / `andWhere` and dynamically change it.

Comment: My conditions vary so I need to assign a variable. What is the way to do this? I know how to use `ActiveQuery` as you have stated but I need my `$conditions`  to change according to different situations.

Comment: Please provide more details about how it can change.

Comment: I have, please also note that assigning variable `$conditions` is completely valid.

Comment: Not the way you initially wrote it (with comma).

Comment: True, I initially wrote it with errors to show what I needed to achieve.

Comment: The given solution seems to work fine only when [I do not filter using this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22972500/3128638). I now need to find out what is causing the DB exception

Comment: Without seeing what you added and exception details, it's impossible to help.